# Javascript scoping issues cant access vars at run time event

Tags: javascript, scope

I can't seem to get access a param defined by the calling function - myfunction within the called function method2. Any idea what I'm doing wrong. I have a feeling I'm stumbling into closures I'm not sure.

```
    function myfunction(){
      var config = { alpha: 1, beta:2, charlie:3}
      $(someelement).on('event', function(a,b,config){
          //a and b are published established params of the event im using
          //config is something im adding
          method2(a, b, config);
      });
    }
    function method2(a,b,c){
      //param c is undefined why ??
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have `config` in your declared function arguments:

```
$(someelement).on('event', function(a,b,config){
// Here --------------------------------^    
    method2(a, b, config);
});
```

That shadows (hides) the `config` you've declared in the enclosing function. If you remove it:

```
$(someelement).on('event', function(a,b){
// Removed ----------------------------^    
    method2(a, b, config);
});
```

The argument no longer shadows (hides) the variable.

Problem is that third parameter of the function is also named `config`, and when it is not passed (since jquery `on` does not have three parameters), it is set to `undefined`.